# test class for simple apex code

Tags: unit-test

i need to write test class for this class but i m not getting percentage please can any one help on this

```
public class MyClass {
    Integer myInteger = 10;
    public void myMethod (Integer multiplier) {
        Integer multiplicationResult;
        multiplicationResult=multiplier*myInteger;
        System.debug('Multiplication is '+multiplicationResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make an attempt before people will help you.  What test code have you written so far?

Comment: @istest
public class testMyClass {

static testmethod void getmethod(){

MyClass my = new MyClass();
my.myMethod(80);
}
}

Comment: i know this is not correct way i need some other way test class for this code

Comment: Please update your original post with the test code.  It looks like that should work to give you coverage.  Which lines are not covered?  Also, you should add an assertion to make the test meaningful.  See https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/apex_testing

Answer (score 0):

**Test Class :**  Remove *Integer* when calling your method, You need not to define Datatype of your parameter while calling the method. Following code should work now for 100% coverage.

```
@istest public class testMyClass { 

static testmethod void getmethod(){ 
       MyClass my = new MyClass(); 
       my.myMethod(80); 
} 
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between that and the code that @hari p posted?

Comment: Sorry @Rob - But I guess that comment is edited again, there was small mistake in it --- earlier there was "Integer" datatype  written while calling myMethod like  my.myMethod(Integer 80)
, and as Stackexchange policy code shouldn't be in Comments, coz its not readable

Comment: and Comments will show you the the Timestamp when it is posted not edited. I am damn sure that was the mistake there.

Comment: Ah, I should have spotted that - cheers Nilesh!